# NSTextField's -allowsExpansionToolTips not working after programmatically changing constraints

Tags: objective-c, macos, nslayoutconstraint, nstextfield, appkit

I have an NSTextField, for which I've set -allowsExpansionToolTips to YES.

The expansion tooltip works nicely, until I programmatically change a constraint of that text field (thereby altering its frame/bounds), after which the expansion tooltip no longer works.

***What I've tried, to no avail:***

- Setting -allowsExpansionToolTips to NO, then back to YES
- Setting its -stringValue to an empty string, then back to its
  original value
- Setting the textField's cell to a newly created NSTextFieldCell
- Different variations and combinations of the above

Basically, I've tried nothing and I'm all out of ideas...

**I've uploaded an Xcode sample project (Xcode 9.4) to my website so you can take a look:**
*https://eternalstorms.at/bugreports/ExpansionTooltipTest.zip*

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thank you kindly,

Matthias

Comment: Try `invalidateCursorRectsForView:`.

Comment: that worked wonderfully, thank you.
Please feel free to submit this as an "answer", not a comment, and I'll mark it as solved.
Thanks again, Willeke!

A typical case of looking in the wrong place. I was looking at NSView and NS*Cell, but, of course, not NSWindow. ‍♂️